# is it possible to upload an image with only jquery with out using any php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

i am trying to upload an image with Ajax/jquery without refreshing and also without using any php in back-end.
i searched alot but all are using php at back-end, my requirement is not to use php.

http://www.9lessons.info/2011/08/ajax-image-upload-without-refreshing.html

http://dondedeportes.es/uploader-previewer/

if not possible without php . please suggest me some alternatives .

Comment: Why do you want to avoid server side script to upload images?

Comment: *"i am trying to upload an image"* Upload it *where*?

Comment: if client-side scripting was enough to upload an image and put it into a server filesystem, it would be a huge security hole

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not possible to upload an image without some kind of backend to process the upload.

Comment: thanks for your answer ? is their any alternatives without php??

Comment: @user1430001 There are a lot of alternatives, what are your specifications? What kind of server side resources can you use?

Comment: There's any number of server side technologies you could use, Perl, Python, Ruby, node.js, ASP.NET, even C++ or assembly language if you're feeling particularly brave.  There just has to be something there that can process the submitted data.

Answer (score 0):

You can't *upload* the image to the server without server-side processing.

If your goal is just to show the image in the page, *without* uploading it to the server (perhaps as a preview), that's possible on newer browsers via a combination of the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) and a [`data:` URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme). The File API gives you *client-side* access to the file a user identifies, including the ability to read its contents; and a `data:` URI lets you put an image on the page using the data from that image file.

Comment: yeah my requirements are sort of previewing image without uploading, for the time being. is it possible to upload to the server side after it ?

Comment: @user1430001: If you're using the File API, the way you gain access to the file is via an `<input type="file">` element. You can put that in a form, use it for live preview, and then if the user confirms by sending the form, the browser will upload the file to the server. In the end, though, it still requires something server-side to *receive* the upload. And note that the File API [isn't supported yet by any version of IE](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi) although support may be coming in IE10. And Safari's support may not be enough for what you need.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of server are you using? If it supports Webdav, you could use [a Javascript Webdav-Client](http://debris.demon.nl/projects/davclient.js/doc/README.html). But for this, the server has to be configured.